# clear cache when loading an image - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Good day, I have a problem when I load an image with a special name, for example image3.jpg and later the image3.jpg was replaced but it has the same name when I reload it, it stays in the cache in reactjs and the previous image appears before be replaced and so refresh the browser the previous image continues to appear, how do I keep it from being cached and every time I change the image with the same name it is updated:

```js
<img src="https://parqueoenvia.co/apiParqueoenvia/publicidad_img/Imagenes/publicidad3.jpg" />
```

Comment: i have the same problem. im trying to update my users profile photo. when i inspect the img, source of the image appears as my new profile photo but it seems old photo stays on dom. I tested all possibilities. problem neither on react nor in backend.  my photos stored in amazon s3. I suspect that my problems origin is amazon s3.